# How to use defclass in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, accurev

Since I would like to use accurev from emacs, I tried using this .el module:
https://github.com/shellbj/vc-accurev. However, I get the following error on both emacs 23.4.1 and 24.3:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function defclass)
  (defclass vc-accurev-object nil ((node-name :initform ... :type symbol :allocation :class :documentation "XML node name")) :abstract t)
  eval-current-buffer()
  call-interactively(eval-current-buffer t nil)
  execute-extended-command(nil)
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

I'm running native emacs on windows 7. Can someone kindly help me make this run so I can manipulate accurev from emacs? I'm also curious about learning how to use EIEIO (which is the package that apparently implements this defclass extension). Bing/Google searching did not reveal a require statement.

Thanks
Siegfried

Comment: Like this? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eieio/

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CEDET_Quickstart has simply `(require 'eieio)`